# Simple custom deleter lambda supplied to std::unique_ptr: why use by-reference capture default ([&]) over no-capture ([])?

Tags: c++, lambda

### Background

Cppreference:s [section on `std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) shows the following demo for supplying a custom deleter to the `unique_ptr` instance:

> ```
> std::unique_ptr<D, std::function<void(D*)>> p(new D, [&](D* ptr)
> {
>     std::cout << "destroying from a custom deleter...\n";
>     delete ptr;
> });
> ```

Where `D`, for the purpose of this question, is just as simple custom type, say

```
struct D
{
    D() { std::cout << "D CTOR\n"; }
    ~D() { std::cout << "D DTOR\n"; }
};
```

Moreover, the reference above states the following type requirement on the deleter:

> **Type requirements**
>
> `Deleter` must be `FunctionObject` or lvalue reference to a
>   `FunctionObject` or lvalue reference to function, callable with an
>   argument of type `unique_ptr<T, Deleter>::pointer`
>
> ...
>
> **Member types**
>
> `pointer`: `std::remove_reference<Deleter>::type::pointer` if that type exists, otherwise `T*`. Must satisfy `NullablePointer`.

As a capture list of the deleter lambda in the example above, `[&]` is used. Based on Cppreference:s [section on lambdas](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda), as I see it, the only effect of this capture list in the deleter example above would be to capture the *"current object by reference"* [emphasis mine]:

> `[&]` captures all automatic variables odr-used in the body of the
>   lambda by reference and **current object by reference if exists**.

But as I understand it from above, the supplied lambda will be simply called with the object's `unique_ptr<T, Deleter>::pointer`, no matter if we choose `[&]` or `[]` as capture list to the lambda. I don't understand myself why we'd want to use by-reference capture (of the *object*, which is the `unique_ptr` instance here?) default here, but I'm pretty sure I'm missing something essential (hence the question).

### Question

- Is there any particular reason to use by-reference capture default (`[&]`) in the deleter lambda in the example above, as compared to simply using no-capturing (`[]`)?

Comment: Not much closer to an answer, but the "current object" would be the instance of which `p` is a member function, i.e. `*this`. If `p` is not a member function, this is irrelevant (hence "if exists").

Comment: I think it's just a typo, or the author of the example didn't care much. After all, this doesn't make the example less valid, does it?

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall Thanks for the feedback. I'm not so much interested in the validity of the example but rather if I'm missing some essential intent with the choice of capture list (as I'm not very well-versed in these parts of C++). If the answer is, _"probably no particular intent; both alternatives are valid"_, then I'm content with such an answer.

Comment: @Quentin I see, that would go in line with SingerOfTheFall's comment above, since the `[&]` would seemingly be redundant in this particular case (I mistakenly thought that the "current object" would be the `unique_ptr` itself, as it is the supplier of the argument when calling the deleter).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's what the standard says about the deleter of `unique_ptr` (**[unique.ptr.single]/1**):

> A client-supplied template argument
>   D
>   shall be a function object type (20.9), lvalue-reference to function, or lvalue-reference to function object type
>   for which, given a value
>   d
>   of type
>   D
>   and a value
>   ptr
>   of type
>   unique_ptr::pointer
>   , the expression
>   d(ptr)
>   is valid and has the effect of disposing of the pointer as appropriate for that deleter.

Judging by the above, both `[]` and `[&]` are perfectly valid.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In the example in my question, the deleter is a function object type, right? I don't quite follow how the standard quote above can be directly applied to the analysis of the different captures in the lambda (`[&]` vs `[]`; equivalence, here?); are using these alternatives fully equivalent here or will using one over the other mean different types for the template argument `D`? (As I see it, it's a function object type for both cases, but I might be wrong). I'd be grateful if you could expand the reasoning of how these two are equivalent (or not) in this example.

Comment: Each lambda has it's own unique type, so it's always "different types for the template argument D". However, the only requirement given for the deleter is that it should properly delete the pointer when called in the form of `d(ptr)`. Anything else regarding how exactly it works (including it's internal structure) is irrelevant. Thus I conclude that [] and [&] lambdas are equivalent in this case (because capturing or not capturing additional data doesn't change the deleter behavior).